# Parse dict into specific list format using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Say I have the following dict

```
{'red':'boop','white':'beep','rose':'blip'}
```

And I want to get it to a list like so

```
['red','boop','end','white','beep','rose','blip','end']
```

The key / value which is to be placed in front of the list is an input.

So I essentially I want `[first_key, first_value,end, .. rest of the k/v pairs..,end]`

I wrote a brute force approach but I feel like there's a more pythonic way of doing it (and also because once implemented the snippet would make my code O(n^2) )

```
for item in lst_items    
    data_lst = []
    for key, value in item.iteritems():
        data_lst.append(key)
        ata_lst.append(value)
    #insert 'end' at the appropiate indeces
 #more code ...
```

Any pythonic approach?

Comment: How do we know what is the first key, dictionaries are unordered in some versions of python

Comment: the k/v pair to be placed in the first section of the list is specified previously in the code. I will update my question to reflect this

Comment: Also, why do you think your approach would be O(n^2), it looks O(n) to me

Comment: I don't remember why, but at some point [sorteddict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) was better than collections.OrderedDict.

Comment: I updated my questions with the appropriate edits

Comment: `the k/v pair to be placed in the first section of the list is specified`. Where is it specified? **Dictionaries in Python 2.7 are unordered.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below relies on [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the items into a single list.  We pull the first two values from the `chain` and then use them to build a new list, which we extend with the rest of the values.

```
from itertools import chain

def ends(d):
    if not d:
        return []
    c = chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems())
    l = [next(c), next(c), "end"]
    l.extend(c)
    l.append("end")
    return l

ends({'red':'boop','white':'beep','rose':'blip'})
# ['rose', 'blip', 'end', 'white', 'beep', 'red', 'boop', 'end']
```

If you know the key you want first, and don't care about the rest, we can use a lazily evaluated generator expression to remove it from the flattened list.

```
def ends(d, first):
    if not d:
        return []
    c = chain.from_iterable((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if k != first)
    l = [first, d[first], "end"]
    l.extend(c)
    l.append("end")
    return l

ends({'red':'boop','white':'beep','rose':'blip'}, 'red')
# ['red', 'boop', 'end', 'rose', 'blip', 'white', 'beep', 'end']
```

Comment: How about `l = [next(c), next(c), "end", *c, "end"]`? Or `[next(c), next(c), "end"] + list(c) + ["end"]` for Python 2.7

Comment: @tobias_k The question is tagged [tag:python-2.7]

Comment: Mostly gorgeous. But wouldn't popping out `first` from the dict before chaining be more efficient than using the if test within the loop?

Comment: @SeyiShoboyejo Probably.  It would mutate the dictionary though, which isn't what someone would expect this to do. I'm happier trading a little speed for referential transparency.

Comment: Maybe popping and re-inserting for me. Especially if the dict were sufficiently large. But that is nitpicking; I know hehe...

Answer (score 1):

The first key is specified in `first` variable:

```
first = 'red'

d = {'red':'boop','white':'beep','rose':'blip'}

new_l = [first, d[first], 'end']
for k, v in d.items():
    if k == first:
        continue
    new_l.append(k)
    new_l.append(v)
new_l.append('end')
print(new_l)
```

Prints:

```
['red', 'boop', 'end', 'white', 'beep', 'rose', 'blip', 'end']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate` and check the current index:

```
>>> d = {'red':'boop','white':'beep','rose':'blip'}
>>> [x for i, e in enumerate(d.items())
...    for x in (e + ("end",) if i in (0, len(d)-1) else e)]
...
['white', 'beep', 'end', 'red', 'boop', 'rose', 'blip', 'end']
```

However, your original idea, first chaining the keys and values and then inserting the `"end"` items would not have O(n²), either. It would be O(n) followed by another O(n), hence still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
data_lst = [x for k, v in lst_itemsL.iteritems() for x in (k, v) ] 
data_lst.insert(2, 'end') 
data_lst.append('end')
```

This is pythonic; though will likely have the same efficiency (which can't be helped here). 
This should be faster than placing if blocks inside the loops...

Comment: This will put an `end` after every key/value pair, not just the first and last.

Comment: Okay. I didn't get the full details before. Let me try and update my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*item.items())) + ['end']
```

Comment: It's less convoluted if you use the `.items()` method instead of a comprehension: `list(itertools.chain(*d.items())) + ['end']`